# How can I change screen title in page

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Modules:

```
"react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
"react": "16.8.3",
"expo": "^33.0.0",
```

I tried

```
    Actions.refresh({title:'newTitle'})
```

But it happened.
[image: two muppets]

I want to change title not back title

Comment: Where is the title you want to change?

Comment: I want to look like this. https://i.ibb.co/9HJwyCB/Ekran-Resmi-2019-08-19-21-43-59.png

Comment: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3071 does this help?

Comment: this is not work :(

Comment: Try <Scene key="key" component={component} title="your title"/>

Comment: This is working well but I want to this Dynamic!

Answer (score 0):

Please try 
`Actions.replace(SCENEKEY, {title: 'New Page Title'})`